# Maps - when pins are loaded on the map and user moves map, how to only load new pins and not the ones already loaded?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.maps

I'm trying to load only new pins when a user moves the map, like, he sees pins, then makes a move to a side and new pins load and get displayed on the map but the ones that were displayed already don't need to load up again, they just stay there.

I know how to refresh the map etc. but I don't want to load all the pins every time the user moves the map, I want the ones already displayed to stay and the new ones to load on the map.

I thought about adding the pins to a `List<Pin>` and when I need to load new places I could add the new ones to the list, but then it reloads the whole list and so the current pins are reloaded as well.

If you could share the way to do it so that I can understand the thought process and then I can share code if needed because otherwise it's going to be a super long post with a bunch of code that might not be needed to understand how to do it.

Comment: This is just the way the map control works.  If you need different behavior you need to use a different map control

Comment: I see, but is there a way to do it using this one ? Like, do I need to create a custom renderer or is there a function for it ?

Comment: No, there is not, as I already said.

Comment: I see, so to try to emulate this as close as I can and reload the pins as fast as possible, could I for example add all the current loaded pins to the device's cache and when it loads new pins, add them to the cache as well so that it has them in memory when reloading the pins ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ObservableCollection instead of List in ViewModel.

```
public ObservableCollection<Pin> Locations { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Pin>();
```

And if you add new pin,

```
Locations.Add(NewLocation());
```

Each time add a new item in Locations, it will notify the changes and don't have to set a new value to Locations. This will be more convenient.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: You're right ! I forgot about it. Thank you so much. Also to make sure I understand this right before making this the answer, if I add the `ObservableCollection` to the device's cache, will it make it faster when it loads new pins, or am I mixing up the way it works ?

Comment: I am afraid there is not much effect. Although add to cache may improve load speed, Map control still need time to render.